# Start a selenium hub on a remote machine programmatically

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-grid, selenium-grid2

How can we start a selenium grid hub on a remote machine programmatically?

As of now, i know the following ways of doing it but i have some questions on those.

> Approach 1: Execute a batch file on remote machine with required
>   command (java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.14.0.jar -role hub) 
>   to start the hub. (using PSExec to execute command on remote machine)

*No questions and issues with above approach. But looking for an API way of doing this*.

> Approach 2: [This](https://gist.github.com/krmahadevan/1106183) approach (I didn't try this way since these are
>   JAVA APIs and i have very little knowledge in JAVA).

*Q1: Can we use the above approach to start the hub on a remote machine?*

*Q2: Does selenium server jar file is required in this approach?*

Can we use [these](https://github.com/nicegraham/selenium-grid2-api) APIs in our program (some how making a POST or GET http request with required [configuration in JSON](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/java/server/src/org/openqa/grid/common/defaults/DefaultHub.json)) to configure Hub on a remote machine and start it? (I know console way of using these APIs with selenium server jar file)

Answer (score 0):

The only way to start selenium grid is by running command on remote machine using the below command

java -jar Selenium-server.jar -role hub

you can make a batch file for this command to ease of use specifiy the name of jar file with your file

Answer (score -1):

Try this 
RemoteWebDriver rWD = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://" + {{Hub_Name}}+ ":4444/wd/hub"),desiredCapabilities);